# SSL_CTX_new() hangs on ARM architecture

Tags: c, openssl, embedded, freeze

I am working on a cross-compile project, implementing an HTTPS connection. My code builds and runs fine in the `qemu-arm` emulator, but when running on the actual hardware, it hangs on `SSL_CTX_new`.

This is the code I use to initialise my SSL context:

```
SSL_CTX *_https_initialise_context() {
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *_ctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();

    method = TLS_client_method();
    // This is where the program hangs
    _ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);

    if (_ctx == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    return _ctx;
}
```

The device the code is running on is old, and does not have a lot of resources (32M RAM, running on a 192MHz ARM processor), but when checking `top`, the process does not seem to be CPU bound. (it stays at 0% CPU and 13% RAM)

Is TLS too much for this device, or could I update my code to get this running?

Comment: What did you set up for source of random?

Comment: @stark Nothing. All examples I found do not mention that. How could I set that up?

Comment: LMGTFY https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers

Comment: I linked `/dev/random` to `/dev/urandom` and it works, but I don't know if that should be the "right" way to do it

Comment: It all depends how secure you want to be. I've done everything from seed with a fixed value to using a hardware RNG, depending on the application.  If you are generating the root certificate for a CA then you  aren't "right".  For most purposes what you did is fine. (** Waiting for the howls from people who think there is good and bad entropy **).

Comment: And beware that reading `/dev/random`  may block your application if there are not enough 'entropy' bytes available.  This is why `/dev/urandom` should preferably be used. The [Myths about /dev/urandom](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/)  article may be  an interesting reading.